# Error creating table with CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql, syntax, mariadb

I have an issue, I am getting the following error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `methods` (   `ID` int(11) NOT NULL
>   AUTO_INCREMENT, ' at line 14

When I try and do this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `methods` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `friendly` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=29 ;
```

I was wondering if anyone could help me, because in all honesty, I'm not too good with this stuff

Comment: This works just fine when I paste it into my mysql client. Perhaps you forgot a `;` in the previous statement?

Comment: I'll have a look now, as I said, i'm terrible xD

Comment: Thanks Mureinik, I must have had a moment, put a , instead of a ;